# Cloud Firestore and Google Cloud Credentials

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have some javascript code running on Firebase Functions, mostly it works fine, retrieving data from Firestore using this at first:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let db = admin.firestore();
```

Sometimes I get an error:

> "Error getting document Error: Could not load the default credentials."

How can it work sometimes and give this error randomly?

Answer (score 0):

You can  add the serviceAccountKey.json to your project and changed the imports with the provided code:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');    
var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
 databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com'
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  As I said it worked sometimes even without credentials because it's just writing to firestore.

I found out that I had to wait until the promise was returned before sending the response which ends the function.

let setDoc = db.collection('sweepstakes1').doc('unsub').set(newinfo2)

  .then (doc => {

res.status(200).send("response");
return null;

    })

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to wait until the promise was returned before sending the response which ends the function.

```
  let setDoc = 
  db.collection('sweepstakes1').doc('unsub').set(newinfo2) 
  .then (doc => { res.status(200).send("response"); return 
  null; })
```